# DNS resolution of machines connected from VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, rras

I have this private network, 10.0.0.0.

On this network, two servers :

- SVR-DC1 , a domain controller / dns server with only 1 network interface : its ip is 10.0.0.5.
- SVR-REMOTE , a RRAS / VPN server / DHCP / NAP with 2 interfaces , 10.0.0.2 and a public one.

Ok so plenty of clients (domain computers) join my private network through SVR-REMOTE. Once, for example, CLI-FRANCK join the vpn , it can ping and resolve SVR-DC1 and other machines from the private network, but no other machine connected through the VPN. No one can ping CLI-FRANCK or CLI-FRANCK.MYDOMAIN.ORG unless we ping directly the IP : SVR-DC1, SVR-REMOTE, CLI-MYRIAM also on the VPN, noone can resolve CLI-FRANCK.

Did i miss a setting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your Client machines registering DNS records through the DNS server specified in the VPN DHCP scope?

If SRV-DC1 is a global catalog, I would check the AD-integrated zone to see if VPN'd CLI machines are in there.

Edit: Also have a look at the settings in the VPN adapter on the client machine...
[pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rajsi.jpg)

Comment: the edit did it